# Can DateTimePicker in C# forms have miliseconds?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I used a custom format for the datetimepicker "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" which displays in the control:

"2022-11-21 11:39:26.fff"

I need to retrieve a date from a SQL db that has miliseconds in it for my CRUD, but when it comes to update a record, it looses the miliseconds, any advice about it?

I expect to fill a DateTime object with the value: 2022-11-21 11:39:26.**336** for a later update on db.

but I get Instead 2022-11-21 11:39:26.**000**

Comment: If you look at the documentation for the [DateTimePicker.CustomFormat Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat) you will see that it does not include "fff" in the list of all the valid format strings. Do you need the user to be able to alter the milliseconds part?

Comment: Yes, the user should be able to edit the miliseconds

Comment: Or maybe you could have a DTP for the date and something like [Time Picker](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170684/Time-Picker) for the time part (with milliseconds).

Comment: The `DateTimePicker` doesn't support editing the milliseconds part. I guess a human being has no point editing it because it's useless. Other than that, why don't store your datetime value as long-typed ticks in your database ? You can build back a new datetime with it like : `DateTime dt = new DateTime(ticks);`